HTML file Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
I have an HTML file, where I joined a CSS style, JS code for Image Classification and HTML code, from MediaPipe (https://codepen.io/mediapipe-preview/pen/BaVZejK). I created a custom model, .tflite, whose path was added in modelAssetPath:, instead of the default model.
I get the following errors in Debug Console in Chrome:
Access to fetch at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxxxxxxxx/resnet50_quantized.tflite' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

and
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED -- from a public object in Google Cloud Storage

and
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Mh.l (tasks-vision:7:47151)
    at Mh.l (tasks-vision:7:76591)
    at Mh.o (tasks-vision:7:121629)
    at Zo (tasks-vision:7:45744)
    at async createImageClassifier (

In VSCode, I get the following:
Could not read source map for https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/tasks-vision: Unexpected 404 response from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/vision_bundle_mjs.js.map: Failed to resolve the requested file.
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at l (cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/tasks-vision:7:47151)
    at l (cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/tasks-vision:7:76591)
    at o (cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/tasks-vision:7:121629)
    at Zo (cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/tasks-vision:7:45744)
    --- await ---

As my knowledge of JS is quite limited, I'd like to have some ideas about what can be wrong, like position of script, module, href, if possible.
Here is my effort so far:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>

@use "@material";
body {
  font-family: roboto;
  margin: 2em;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  --mdc-theme-primary: #007f8b;
  --mdc-theme-on-primary: #f1f3f4;
}

h1 {
  color: #007f8b;
}

h2 {
  clear: both;
}

video {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

section {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.mdc-button.mdc-button--raised.removed {
  display: none;
}

.removed {
  display: none;
}

.invisible {
  opacity: 0.2; 
}

.videoView,
.classifyOnClick {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.videoView p,
.classifyOnClick p {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #007f8b;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0;
}

.highlighter {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25);
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.classifyOnClick {
  z-index: 0;
  font-size: calc(8px + 1.2vw);
}

.classifyOnClick img {
  width: 100%;
}

.webcamPredictions {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #007f8b;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: calc(8px + 1.2vw);
}

</style>


</head>

<body>
  
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>

<h1>Classifying images using the MediaPipe Image Classifier Task</h1>

<section id="demos" class="invisible">
  <h2>Demo: Classify Images</h2>
  <p><b>Click on an image below</b> to see its classification.</p>
  <div class="classifyOnClick">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/9177687/dog_flickr_publicdomain.jpeg" width="100%" crossorigin="anonymous" title="Click to get classification!" />
    <p class="classification removed">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="classifyOnClick">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/9177687/cat_flickr_publicdomain.jpeg" width="100%" crossorigin="anonymous" title="Click to get classification!" />
    <p class="classification removed">
    </p>
  </div>

  <h2>Demo: Webcam continuous classification</h2>
  <p>Hold some objects up close to your webcam to get real-time classification. For best results, avoid having too many objects visible to the camera.</br>Click <b>enable webcam</b> below and grant access to the webcam if prompted.</p>

  <div class="webcam">
    <button id="webcamButton" class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised">
      <span class="mdc-button__ripple"></span>
      <span class="mdc-button__label">ENABLE WEBCAM</span>
    </button>
    <video id="webcam" autoplay playsinline></video>
    <p id="webcamPredictions" class="webcamPredictions removed"></p>
  </div>
</section>

<script type="module">
import {
  ImageClassifier,
  FilesetResolver
} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/tasks-vision";
const video = document.getElementById("webcam");
const webcamPredictions = document.getElementById("webcamPredictions");
const demosSection = document.getElementById("demos");
let enableWebcamButton;
let webcamRunning = false;
const videoHeight = "360px";
const videoWidth = "480px";

const imageContainers = document.getElementsByClassName(
  "classifyOnClick"
);
let runningMode = "IMAGE";

// Add click event listeners for the img elements.
for (let i = 0; i < imageContainers.length; i++) {
  imageContainers[i].children[0].addEventListener("click", handleClick);
}

// Track imageClassifier object and load status.
let imageClassifier;


const createImageClassifier = async () => {
  const vision = await FilesetResolver.forVisionTasks(
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/tasks-vision@20230919.0.0/wasm"
  );
  imageClassifier = await ImageClassifier.createFromOptions(vision, {
    baseOptions: {
      modelAssetPath: `https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resnet50_quantized.tflite`
    },
    maxResults: 7,
    runningMode: runningMode,
    scoreThreshold: 0.0
  });
  
  // Show demo section now model is ready to use.
  demosSection.classList.remove("invisible");
};
createImageClassifier();

/**
 * Demo 1: Classify images on click and display results.
 */
async function handleClick(event) {
  // Do not classify if imageClassifier hasn't loaded
  if (imageClassifier === undefined) {
    return;
  }
  // if video mode is initialized, set runningMode to image
  if (runningMode === "VIDEO") {
    runningMode = "IMAGE";
    await imageClassifier.setOptions({ runningMode: "IMAGE" });
  }

  // imageClassifier.classify() returns a promise which, when resolved, is a ClassificationResult object.
  // Use the ClassificationResult to print out the results of the prediction.
  const classificationResult = imageClassifier.classify(event.target);
  // Write the predictions to a new paragraph element and add it to the DOM.
  const classifications = classificationResult.classifications;

  const p = event.target.parentNode.childNodes[3];
  p.className = "classification";
  p.innerText =
    "Classificaton: " +
    classifications[0].categories[0].categoryName +
    "\n Confidence: " +
    Math.round(parseFloat(classifications[0].categories[0].score) * 100) +
    "%";
  classificationResult.close();
}

/********************************************************************
// Demo 2: Continuously grab image from webcam stream and classify it.
********************************************************************/

// Check if webcam access is supported.
function hasGetUserMedia() {
  return !!(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia);
}

// Get classification from the webcam
async function predictWebcam() {
  // Do not classify if imageClassifier hasn't loaded
  if (imageClassifier === undefined) {
    return;
  }
  // if image mode is initialized, create a new classifier with video runningMode
  if (runningMode === "IMAGE") {
    runningMode = "VIDEO";
    await imageClassifier.setOptions({ runningMode: "VIDEO" });
  }
  const startTimeMs = performance.now();
  const classificationResult = imageClassifier.classifyForVideo(
      video,
      startTimeMs
    );
  video.style.height = videoHeight;
  video.style.width = videoWidth;
  webcamPredictions.style.width = videoWidth;
  const classifications = classificationResult.classifications;
  webcamPredictions.className = "webcamPredictions";
  webcamPredictions.innerText =
    "Classification: " +
    classifications[0].categories[0].categoryName +
    "\n Confidence: " +
    Math.round(parseFloat(classifications[0].categories[0].score) * 100) +
    "%";
  // Call this function again to keep predicting when the browser is ready.
  if (webcamRunning === true) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(predictWebcam);
  }
}

// Enable the live webcam view and start classification.
async function enableCam(event) {
  if (imageClassifier === undefined) {
    return;
  }

  if (webcamRunning === true) {
    webcamRunning = false;
    enableWebcamButton.innerText = "ENABLE PREDICTIONS";
  } else {
    webcamRunning = true;
    enableWebcamButton.innerText = "DISABLE PREDICTIONS";
  }

  // getUsermedia parameters.
  const constraints = {
    video: true
  };

  // Activate the webcam stream.
  video.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
  video.addEventListener("loadeddata", predictWebcam);
}

// If webcam supported, add event listener to button.
if (hasGetUserMedia()) {
  enableWebcamButton = document.getElementById("webcamButton");
  enableWebcamButton.addEventListener("click", enableCam);
} else {
  console.warn("getUserMedia() is not supported by your browser");
}

</script>

</body>
</html>

Both the default .tflite model and my customized .tflite load in the Chrome address bar, so I don't think it's an object permission. As you can see, the page does not load:


did you enable cross origin support on your google storage bucket?

Wow! Now the images are loading! The only problem now is that when I click the image, it does not classify. Thanks @noamgaash =)

@noamgaash Problem solved, please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it

Enabling cross origin support on your google storage bucket should solve the problem - the has been blocked by CORS policy message indicates that loading those resources from another origin (domain / port) is blocked by the browser in the absence of Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
Good luck :)
